# Java monitor returns wrong value from private variable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, monitor

I'm implementing a barrier in java that when accesed by a thread it creates a new object, with a value from the parameter, stored in a private variable to later be returned. Then, when another thread calls the barrier it completes the former object with this other parameter. The first pair goes on well, the rest receive the same object the first pair created.

```
private Barrier aBarrier;
private boolean first = true;

public synchronized Barrier pairUp(int id){     
    try{
        if(first){
            first = false;

            aBarrier = new Barrier(); aBarrier.setFirst(id);

            wait();
        }
        else{
            first = true;
            aBarrier.setLast(id);

            notify();
        }

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.printf("ERROR");}

    return aBarrier;
}
```

And this would be what every process calling the method above looks like.

```
private int id = ID OF THE PROCESS, 14 RUN CONCURRENTLY SO FROM 0 TO 13 (this is set in the constructor method);
public void run() {
    while(true){
        myBarrier = pairUp(id);
        myBarrier.goThrough();
        //Do stuff that doesn't matter here
        // ....

    }
}
```

A Barrier object contains two integers and a method to do more stuff later.
If I reset the private variable aBarrier to null before or after the calls it always gives null back.
I feel like I'm missing some stupid thing here.

If a process calls the method pairUp() after the first pair it will get the first Barrier.
I use this to diferentiate which process came first in the pairUp method.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Post a complete program reproducing the error. Tell us what you expect the program to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where aBarrier and first are declared. I suspect your problems lie with those variables. We need to see the whole thing.

Comment: Its not related to volatile. Its because of race condition.

Comment: Please tell us what you see that is wrong - I think you had it before but you seem to have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

> A Barrier object contains two integers and a method to do more stuff later. If I reset the private variable aBarrier to null before or after the calls it always gives null back. I feel like I'm missing some stupid thing here.

I think the problem is that you are returning `aBarrier` *after* the wait/notify calls but it might have been changed by subsequent threads.  Storing it in a local variable so it won't be changed is key.

You might also have had multiple versions of the wrapping object so your `synchronized` statement is synchronizing on a different object?

Couple things to note in the code below:

- The `System.out.println(...)` changes the synchronization.  Need to be careful here.
- I used the `aBarrier` being null or not to replace the `first` boolean.

Code:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable {

    private static int NUM_THREADS = 14;
    private static final AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    private static Barrier aBarrier = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // only 1 Foo object
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(foo);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Barrier pairUp(int id) {
        Barrier barrier = aBarrier;
        try {
            if (barrier == null) {
                barrier = new Barrier();
                barrier.first = id;
                aBarrier = barrier;
                wait();
            } else {
                barrier.last = id;
                aBarrier = null;
                notify();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // always a good pattern
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
            barrier = null;
        }
        // return local barrier because aBarrier might have changed
        return barrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int id = idCounter.incrementAndGet();
        while (true) {
            Barrier myBarrier = pairUp(id);
            // System.out.println is synchronized so it may move the bug
            System.out.println(id + ": " + myBarrier.first + " and " + myBarrier.last);
        }
    }

    private static class Barrier {
        int first;
        int last;
    }
}
```